# How to get updated page information through C# WebBrowser when updatePanel AJAX event happens?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, wpf, webbrowser-control

I am automating a scenario in WPF using `WebBrowser`. Code snippet is as follows

```
string id = paginationControlProcessing[1].PageCtrl.id;
webDoc.GetElementById(id).GotFocus += new HtmlElementEventHandler(wb_OnGotFocus_PaginationControls);
webDoc.GetElementById(id).Focus();

webDoc.GetElementById(id).RaiseEvent("onChange");
webDoc.InvokeScript("__doPostBack", new object[] { "ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$pgControl$nextPageLink", "" });
```

When the page changes through pagination control, I am able to hit the event handler for focus change. Problem is happening when pagination controls are hit where I am not able to retrieve the data for 2nd and 3rd page.

I can do the page navigation and it works in the WebBrowser control. Data is also updated in the table to which these ASP.net AJAX controls are attached. In the event handler, when I look into the content of object WebBrowser1, it does not contain the content of new data that appears in the UpdatePanel control. Data for the control when 2 and 3 are clicked comes through [UpdatePanel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386454.aspx) ASP.Net control.

What event can be used to capture the data coming for UpdatePanel control from server?

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve the task specified above is to use [FiddlerCore](https://www.nuget.org/packages/FiddlerCore/) but one has to be aware of the gotchas related to [certificate generation in fiddlercore](http://www.telerik.com/blogs/understanding-fiddler-certificate-generators) since ASP Panel controls use HTTPS mostly. All interactions on Panel control of ASP generates partial POST requests that result in partial responses with [updatePanel](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24178/The-magical-effects-of-the-UpdatePanel-control-in) contents. It does not update the page source nor there is any automatic redirection happening. Once a page is loaded, any interactions happening in Panel controls must be handled by application driving the automation and it cannot be done through [WebBrowser](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) as it is unaware of any update in the page. Be aware that UpdatePanel responses can also update the __VIEWSTATE and other hidden values. Use fiddler to capture responses and then re create them using custom processing through [HttpWebRequest](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). [HttpClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) is not suitable for most cases since it needs a separate thread to handle async task and then it can become messy to handle events passing between UI, WebBrowser, Fiddler thread and HttpClient tread.

A good place to get help on usage of FiddlerCore is at the [Google group for Fiddler](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/httpfiddler).